# Callable cloud functions - handle error in android

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

im trying to delete an user from firestore and from auth.

I have this callable cloud function:

```
export const deleteUser = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    const userEmail = data.userEmail;
    const collection = data.collection;
    
    try {
        deleteUserByEmail(userEmail, collection)
        return "deleted!"
    } catch (error) {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('invalid-argument', 'there is no user with that email', error);
    }
})

async function deleteUserByEmail(userEmail: string, collection: string) {
    const auth = admin.auth();
    const db = admin.firestore();
    
    const { uid } = await auth.getUserByEmail(userEmail);
    
    await db.collection(collection)
        .doc(uid)
        .delete();
    await auth.deleteUser(uid);
    
    return uid;
}
```

in android i have this:

```
fun deleteFromFirebase(){
        val data = hashMapOf(
            "userEmail" to user.email,
            "collection" to "User"
        )

        functions // Optional region: .getInstance("europe-west1")
            .getHttpsCallable("deleteUser")
            .call(data)
            .addOnCompleteListener() { task ->
                if(!task.isSuccessful)
                {
                    Log.d("User", "ERROR")
                    val e = task.exception
                    if (e != null) {
                        Log.d("Admin", e.message.toString())
                    }
                }else{
                    Log.d("User", "Deleted")
                    //make something
                }
            }
    }
```

If the user in auth and the document nin firestore exist, works great.
But i tryed to generate some error.

So I deleted the user from auth and ran the function. The Android log says `D/User: User deleted`
but in the console from google cloud:

> Function execution took 1878 ms, finished with status code: 200
> Exception from a finished function: Error: There is no user record corresponding to the provided identifier.

How can I handle the error and get correctly in android? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `deleteUserByEmail` function is [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Your `return` statement runs before the promises is resolved. Try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
export const deleteUser = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const userEmail = data.userEmail;
  const collection = data.collection;

  try {
    // add await, continues after Promise is resolved
    await deleteUserByEmail(userEmail, collection)
    return "deleted!"
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error) // <-- check for any errors
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('invalid-argument', 'there is no user with that email', error);
  }
})

async function deleteUserByEmail(userEmail: string, collection: string) {
  const auth = admin.auth();
  const db = admin.firestore();

  const { uid } = await auth.getUserByEmail(userEmail);

  return await Promise.all([
    db.collection(collection).doc(uid).delete(),
    auth.deleteUser(uid)
  ])
}
```

Comment: Thanks, works greate but i have two questions:

Why getUserByEmail is separately from the other two promises?
and what is returned by deleteUserByEmail? Only the promise from db.collection().doc.().delete and from auth.deleteUser(), but not from getUserByEmail?

Comment: @Electrocode [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) runs all the promises simultaneously so you won't be able to use result of one in another. Here we need value of `uid` to we must ensure that promise runs before the other 2 as uid is a dependency for them. `deleteUserByEmail` returns an array containing result of both the promises in `Promise.all`

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! The last question: If i want to return also the uid or the promise frome getUserByEmail, can i concat with the other two?

Comment: @Electrocode something like [this](https://pastebin.com/SugziKtZ) should do. Again can be changed to what data you want to return.